# i have an error when I want to install( npm i --global @adonisjs/cli )

Tags: node.js, npm, adonis.js

while I install (npm i --global @adonisjs/cli) I have an error

```sh
$ npm i --global @adonisjs/cli
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).
npm WARN deprecated set-value@1.0.0: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/afshin/.npm/_logs/2021-03-02T05_09_22_618Z-debug.log
```

Comment: using ubuntu linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I saw an error is related to permission. SO you need to execute the command with the help of "sudo" like,

```
sudo npm i --global @adonisjs/cli
```